# Customize Picture in Picture window?

Tags: web

Browsers have their different implementation for picture-in-picture support. I want my website to have a consistent view for users. How could I implement my own pip window UI?

This is what pip window looks like in chrome.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbObD.jpg)